# Google's Youtube Data API v3 - Why Is My IP Being Refused?

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using PHP/curl to request a Playlist search and had everything working on my local machine.

Now that I move the project onto my web server, I'm getting an error:

*There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.*

I guarantee that:
a) The Youtube data API is enabled in Google Developer Console
b) The API Key is working (as the curl request worked from my local machine)
c) I have done an external IP lookup on my domain name and entered the IP into the permitted IP addresses for this API key in Google Developer Console.

So, given these things, why would I still be refused by Google with that error message?

Comment: Are you certain requests from your server come from the same IP as your public domain? Often they don't.

Comment: Do `var_dump($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'])` to check.

Comment: @sjagr - is there any othe way to find out? I get an undefined index error with that suggestion.

Comment: Try `var_dump(file_get_contents('https://shtuff.it/myip/short/'));` to get your actual server IP when it tries to connect to *the outside*. If that doesn't work, [ifconfig.co](http://ifconfig.co/) should work. Remember to access it from your *server*.

Comment: @h2ooooooo - if you add this comment as an answer, I can accept it as the correct one. This did the trick and allowed me to find the IP address to add to the safe list.

Answer (score 0):

When you are testing on your local machine, you create a key as "installed application" as it's running locally.

When you are hosting it on a web server, you'll create a key as "web application" and you'll give "authorized origin" and "redirect uri".

Comment: Hi Ibrahim, I'm not sure I understand. I'm not using oAuth2 authentication, I'm using an API key. I don't see an option in Google Developer Console to create a web application key - there is only the option to create an OAuth key or a public API key, and I'm using public API.

Answer (score 0):

You must get your server's IP Address (ssh in and use the `ifconfig` command, or login to your cpanel and get your IP Address from there).  Then you must add this address as an authorized user of your YouTube API Key.  You will set this in the API Manager under Credentials, from the Google Developer's Console.